# Internet via one interface, local net via another on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, routing

I have a local net, 192.168.24.0/24, with various machines in it. My internet gateway is on 192.168.24.4.

On a Windows 10 box, I would like to accomplish the following:

- all traffic going to 192.168.24.0/24 should use the wired network interface.
- all traffic going to other IP's than 192.168.24.0/24 should use the wireless network interface.

Is this doable?

Comment: "can someone steer me in the right direction"  Yup, open a command prompt and type `route /?`. :)